# how to make a service that converts documents to presentations with node.js

Tags: node.js, openoffice.org, document-conversion

I want to make a node.js server that converts documents into ppt presentations. I think I will use Open Office for this job but I am not sure how to start and if someone can help into pointing me towards a good direction and maybe some tutorials on how to use Open Office maybe in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planing on doing the conversion yourself, you should start by finding a command line tool or a node.js library that does the conversion. Then build the web service around it.